# Which has more power loss, long wire DC or DC with inverter?

Tags: ac, dc

If I have a battery 12v and want to run like 8 to 10 meter wire (use like 14/16 awg)

What has more power loss,

A.12v dc to a 12v dc bulb 10 watts

B.12v dc to a inverter 220v (1000watts it has like exhaust small fan) to AC bulb 10 watts

Comment: In such a trivial application, simplicity would likely dominate over concerns of efficiency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'An inverter' is rather poorly specified, it may have 80% efficiency, or 98%.

At 8-10 m, even if the wire did have a slightly larger loss, it may be worth it for the simplicity of avoiding an inverter.

It's fairly easy to calculate the loss of the direct connection using the resistivity of copper (1 m of 1 mm<sup>2</sup> copper is about 17 mΩ at room temperature). You do the conversion from 14/16 awg to mm<sup>2</sup>.

You would have to measure the inverter. At 1000 W, running a 10 W load may well be quite inefficient, those 'near 100%' figures I've suggested above are for full load. If I was designing a 1 kW inverter, I may be quite happy with 10 W of no-load losses (only 1% of full load), which would slash its efficiency to < 50% at a 10 W load.